# getting joined tables id instead main table in blade

Tags: php, laravel

Do I need to specify main table's name in order to get that tables id instead joined table's id , My codes are (from controller ) :

```
public function RegistrationEditView(Request $r,$id){
    $data=DB::table('bootcamp_users')->leftJoin('countries_detailed', function($join) {
        $join->on('countries_detailed.id', '=', 'bootcamp_users.country_id');
    })->where('bootcamp_users.id',$id)->first();
    $course_lists=DB::table('course_languages')->get();
    $bootcamps=DB::table('bootcamp_users')->get();
    return view('admin.registeredBootcamp.edit',compact('data','course_lists','bootcamps'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the default `SELECT` behaviour of Laravel's query builder is `SELECT *` so any column sharing the same name in a joined table will overwrite the original selected table's columns: that's why you see `countries_detailed.id` instead of `bootcamp_users.id`.

I suggest specifying a custom select statement to only select needed columns from both tables, for example:

```php
$data = DB::table('bootcamp_users')
  ->select(['bootcamp_users.id', /* Add all needed columns here */])
  ->leftJoin('countries_detailed', function($join) {
      $join->on('countries_detailed.id', '=', 'bootcamp_users.country_id');
  })->where('bootcamp_users.id',$id)->first();
```

Comment: where should I use select, if you kindly tell

Comment: @azim I've updated my answer providing a code example, hope it helps! :)

Comment: what if I need both tables id

Comment: @azim In that case you can use DB::raw to create column aliases, something like so `->select(DB::raw('bootcamp_users.id as bu_id, countries_detailed.id as cd_id, ...'))`, more info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions)